# Why is Laravel using a different mail driver for queued e-mails?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

In development mode, I was using `mailtrap` to test e-mails. Bulk e-mails were working fine too with queues. When I moved my application to production mode, I was unable to send bulk e-mails using the queue.

When I tried to use my production mail driver SparkPost in development mode to check if something is wrong with e-mails, I found that I was able to send e-mails directly. E-mails like password resets were working fine. But when I tried to send bulk e-mails, I was receiving e-mails in the Mailtrap inbox. I cleared the cache using `php artisan cache:clear` but I am still getting e-mails in the Mailtrap inbox while I am using SparkPost credentials in my `.env` file and also `mail.php` file.

Here is my `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sparkpostmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=SMTP_Injection
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_SECRET_LITTLE_KEY
```

The only mention of `smtp.mailtrap.io` is in `.env.example` file. I looked for this host recursively in my whole directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting your laravel queue. The laravel queues caches the config when first starting and doesn't check for further changes, unless it's manually restarted.

You can do that using `php artisan queue:restart`

[See more details in the official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment)

Comment: I have configured supervisor. Is that still okay to use `php artisan queue:restart`? I thought Supervisor uses the latest settings.

Comment: I was trying to solve this issue since last 2 days without sleeping. You just saved my life! It worked.